# Find column number of cell containing numeric value using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel sheet, Value of cell A1 is 1000 whereas that of cell B1 is 10000.

I am trying to find column no. of a cell that contains "1000".

Column no. output I want is 1 (i.e. cell A1) but I am getting output as 2 with below code (referring to value 10000 in cell B1). On the other hand in cell B1 if I replace 10000 by say 10100, I get output of below code as 1.

May I know what change do I need to do in code to get desired output?

*

```
Sub Find_Number()
Dim Find As Range
Set Find = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)).Find("1000")
Debug.Print Find.Column
End Sub
```

*

Comment: Specify the other parameters of `Range.Find`: *After*, *LookIn*, *LookAt*, etc.. *After* should be the last cell.

Comment: If you want to find exactly 1000, then `Application.Match` is another option.

Comment: `LookIn:= xlWhole`. I would rename `Find` to `Found` to avoid using a key word as variable. Also makes statements like these intuitive: `If Not Found is Nothing Then Debug.Print Found.Column`

Comment: Thank you @BigBen

Comment: Thank you @urdearboy for your valuable help & suggestion. Summary is I have to use LookAt:=xlWhole if I use Range.Find or else better use Application.Match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. When using `Find` always advisable to specify the parameters as they may have unexpected settings. By specifying `after` as the last cell in the range the search will start in the first cell rather than skipping it.

And check you've found something before proceeding to avoid errors.

An alternative approach is to use `Match` which will work fine on a 1D range.

(Also I don't like using `Find` as a variable name even if it is allowed.)

```
Sub Find_Number()

Dim rFind As Range

With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5))
    Set rFind = .Find(what:=1000, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) 'might want to specify whole rather than part
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rFind.Column 'avoid error if not found
End With

'alternative
'Dim v As Variant

'v = Application.Match(1000, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)), 0)
'If IsNumeric(v) Then Debug.Print v

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Just one query. 10000 has 1000 in it, that why I got wrong column no. as output since I didn't mention other parameters. So am I expected to mention LookAt:=xlWhole to exactly match my search? (Alternate answer is also awesome. Thank you so much.)

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: Noted your suggestion of not using Find as variable name. Thanks once again for support.